# Check for multiple tables existence using single exists query?

Tags: sql, sybase, exists

I have something like -

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM systable st
                JOIN sysuserperm sup ON st.creator = sup.user_id
                WHERE sup.user_name = 'TEST'
                AND st.table_type = 'BASE'
                AND st.table_name = 'Table1') THEN
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM systable st
                JOIN sysuserperm sup ON st.creator = sup.user_id
                WHERE sup.user_name = 'TEST'
                AND st.table_type = 'BASE'
                AND st.table_name = 'Table2') THEN
```

What's the best way to combine multiple of these in a single exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one out,

```
SELECT  1 
FROM    systable st
        INNER JOIN sysuserperm sup 
            ON st.creator = sup.user_id
WHERE   sup.user_name = 'TEST' AND 
        st.table_type = 'BASE' AND 
        st.table_name IN ('Table1', 'table2')
GROUP   BY sup.user_name, st.table_type
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT st.table_name) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the task

```
IF EXISTS (
    (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLE1') 
    INTERSECT
    (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLE2')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be faster for more rows:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM systable st
                JOIN sysuserperm sup ON st.creator = sup.user_id
                WHERE sup.user_name = 'TEST'
                AND st.table_type = 'BASE'
                AND st.table_name in ('Table1', 'Table2')) THEN
```

Comment: This won't give correct result if one of the tables don't exist. We want to have 1 only if all tables exists.